# Database normalization alternative

Tags: database, normalization

I was wondering if there was any other alternative in order to skip the classical three or more steps normalization in Databases Topic.
Somebody told me that if I used the relational graph technique I could get all my database as a normalized database without having to do all the three or more steps of normalization.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _.. and somebody told me that bananas are growing on the Christmas tree in Lapland_. No. You should not confuse relational DB with graph-oriented DB. Just read about those things. And normalization isn't about "some steps". It's at least about modeling your architecture according to business-rules.

Comment: Ok. I would be more serious. One teacher teached us about the relational graph technique and told showed us that in most cases with this technique you could get all your database tables normalized. Any idea about this?